# Android Studio ShareActionProvider

Tags: android

I added a `ShareActionProvider` menu item to my add, but when I press the "Share" button, the `onOptionsItemSelected` function doesn't capture the event, and I don't succeed to capture the changes in the text (the `shareContent` is initialized with the `onCreate` data through the `onCreateOptionsMenu` function).

I found in old posts that in older versions (support.v7), the "MenuItemCompat" needed to be used, but it's not recognized in `android.widget.ShareActionProvider` class.

This is part of my code:

menu.xml:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_share"
android:title="@string/action_title_share"
android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
android:showAsAction="always" />
```

mainActivity:

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
            // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
            mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) shareItem.getActionProvider();
            setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.getItemId() )
            {
                case R.id.action_share:
                    //share note content
                    noButtonWasPressed = false;
                    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
                    setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
                    return true;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you went through this? https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

Comment: Of course. That's exactly what my code does, but it's not enough. The data is updated onCreateOptionsMenu and I need to update it later, when I press the share button (not when the button is initially displayed)